# How to update page without reloading when folder gets a new item?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm using ajax to fetch data from a folder (images) and append each image into HTML. It works, **but when the folder gets a new image added to it (manually via copy and paste), the page reloads and updates, instead of updating dynamically.**

```
var folder = "./images/"

$.ajax({
    url : folder,
    success : function(data) {
        let a  = $(data).find(".icon-image"); //returns the list of images
        for(let i=0; i<a.length; i++){
            $('.view').append("<img src='./images" + a[i].title + "'>");
        };
    };
});
```

OUTPUT - The code displays all, let's say 5 images from a folder, but if I delete an image from the folder, the page reloads and displays 4 images.

DESIRED OUTPUT - ^The code displays all...delete an image from the folder, **the page displays 4 images without reloading itself.**

Comment: Are you sure there isn't some other snippet of code checking the folder for changes after the page has loaded? What I'm seeing doesn't completely make sense to me.

Comment: Mention how you detect change in files.

Comment: There's nothing in the code you've provided that would ever reload the page. Are you serving the page from a server that also monitors its folder for changes, like browsersync?

Comment: @AuxTaco I am creating a local server using visual studio code i.e. the "Open with Live Server". Is that doing the monitoring?